# LaTeX: Ultisnips

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex

I'm new to Vim and setting up LaTeX with vimtex. Now, I am looking for a Snippet-Manager and decided to give UltiSnips a try. It seems to be very handy.
But it doesn't come with a lot snippets ([honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/tex.snippets) has about 100 snippets).

Now my question: Is there a source providing more snippets (e.g. stuff for mathmode, etc)? Or would somebody be so kind to share his "extended version" of snippets?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it would be more useful to create your own set of snippets: Having more than 100 snippets designed by someone else for someone else's needs is a good way to load your vim with useless stuff. (Also I don't think that the 100 snippets provided by vim-snippets is "not a lot", do you really think you'll use more than that everyday?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to agree, that the best solution is to write my own ones.

Comment: If you have used in the past the vim plugin LaTeX-Suite, you might be familiar withe these snippets https://github.com/kiryph/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/tex_suite.snippets (46 snippets). A cheatsheet can be found here: https://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/vimlatexqrc.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neocomplete is an alternative that may have [different snippets](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet-snippets) and is compatible with the UltiSnips repository.

Other than that if you can't find what you are looking for, you might have to [create your own](https://www.sirver.net/blog/2012/01/08/second-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/) as statox stated.

Answer (score 2):

Like statox said, you should really write you own snippets. But I understand it is nice to have a set to look at, see what others are doing.

One post I thought was really helpful was "[How I'm able to take notes in mathematics lectures using LaTeX and Vim](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/)"

From there, you can also find his github, with all his snippets. I find it a bit too complex, as he defines "math contexts" and global python functions, stuff I don't understand yet.